# Can I change what fields display in Global Search Results?

Tags: lightning, search, search-layout

Currently exploring Lightning, but interested in this question for Classic as well.

When I run a search for my own user name in Lightning, I get the following unhelpful results, which don't differentiate between customer portal user accounts and my internal user login:

[image]

But when I go look at the Search Layouts section for the user object, none of them seem to correspond to this limited field set shown in my search results.

[image]

In particular, the 'Search Results' search layout lists a bunch of fields that don't display for either Classic or Lightning when I do a global search.. so what exactly does that layout handle? According to [this dev documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_relationships_search_layouts.htm) :

> **Search Results - the search results that originate from searching in the left sidebar search of the application or in advanced search.**

Is there a way for me to control the search result fields for specific objects in the global search results, since the results are divided by object anyway?

Comment: I'm not sure about lightning but changing the fields on the search layout works in classic. I just tested in my Sandbox.

Comment: I just tested it in out lightning Sandbox and it works there as well.

Comment: @Toby hey thanks for testing - can you check your search results on the User object specifically? It's working for me on other objects but not the User object.

Comment: I'm not sure about that one. We actually have our own custom VF page for searching users as we have always found the global search to be lacking.

Comment: @smohyee dont know if this helps, but you can leverage towards using a free package to get a better search experience both in visualforce or lightning. https://developers.coveo.com/display/public/SalesforceV2/Getting+Started+with+Coveo+for+Salesforce+Express